# VSCode cppdbg lost options "args" when using "customLaunchSetupCommands"

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode cppdbg debug launch.json, I set a/b/c in "args", but it lost them after I using "customLaunchSetupCommands".

{
"name": "ccc",
"type": "cppdbg",
"request": "launch",
"program": "dddd",
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"stopAtEntry": false,
"externalConsole": false,
"args": [
"a=main",
"b=100",
"c=222"
],

```
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "xxx",
        "targetArchitecture": "x86_64",
        "miDebuggerServerAddress": "",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "customLaunchSetupCommands": [

            {
                "text": "file xxx"
            },
  
        ],
        "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
        "logging": {
            "trace": true,
            "engineLogging": true
        },
    },
```